# Spatial decision support tools for spatial planning, licensing, and permitting, alternative to FlexiCadastre?

Tags: open-source-gis, spatial-database, land-cover, data-management, planning

I'm tasked to design and develop an information management system, i.e. GIS-based spatial decision support system to guide, inform, evaluate, and monitor regulatory processes in spatial planning, licensing, and permitting (e.g. mining, plantation concession, palm oil, timber production, etc.). This system must be simple, light, affordable, and sustainable to support local governments where hardware, internet, funding, and capacity are very limited. An example will be like FlexiCadastre (http://www.spatialdimension.com/Products/FlexiCadastre-Overview)  but should be mostly open-source based and account for slow/unstable local internet and electricity. I'm exploring QGIS plug-ins and would like to get recommendations from our community on other platforms or software to use?

Comment: I think your question is much too broad for our focussed a Q&A format.

Comment: That was the button I was trying to hit but I have large fingers compared to my phone's screen and there is no reopen option on the app.